# How to set default text in TextView to see it in the layout preview while binding?

Tags: android, binding

So I would like to see my layout preview with the fields filled with something like default placeholders but if I use bindings the settext attribute is already used and the fields are showing empty since there is no info from the models yet.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                **android:text="@{showBlueportSpotViewModel.name}"**
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

I tried this:

```
android:text="@{showBlueportSpotViewModel.name ?? @string/blueport_placeholder_name}"
```

but I still see the view empty.

Do you guys any workaround? I guess once a workaround is found, it can be used to ImageView and src for example and etc..

Thank you!

Comment: Use hint. Example -> android:hint="Email"

Comment: hint is not a generic answer that i want but thanks :)

Comment: If you only want to see the text in the layout preview, not when the app is run, you can use tools:text="your placeholder text". More information here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes

Comment: yeah I think yours is similar answer as what I found out thanks!

Comment: @blackcj if you want add an answer and I give it valid because it works for me :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the tools attribute to define properties that will appear in the layout preview but will not appear when you run the app.

Add the following to your root view:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then use the tools attribute to define text that will only appear in the layout preview:

```
tools:text="placeholder text"
```

The tools attribute is very useful when mocking up views in the editor. All of the tools attributes are stripped when the app is packaged. More information here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround

I added

```
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to the layout

and just having duplicated declarations in the view like:

```
android:text="@string/blueport_placeholder_name"
bind:text="@{showBlueportSpotViewModel.name}"
```

or

`android:src="@{showBlueportSpotViewModel.blueportImageDrawable}"
bind:src="@drawable/android_menu_header"`

I don't really know if this has secondary wrong consequences so I won't accept this answer until somebody can comment and say if it is okay.. Thanks!